# Redux reducer is not call after dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Can you explain me why my code is not call my reducer (currently I have only one reducer in the folder) and doesn't activate redux-logger. My console is empty, there is no any information or errors

**The main index.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import  App from './containers/App.jsx';
import * as reducers from './reducers'
import types from './constants/actions';

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);

const destination = document.querySelector("#container");
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(logger)(createStore);

let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, {
userName: 'N/A'
});


ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
</Provider>,
destination
);

console.log(1) //<----- CONSOLE.LOG
store.dispatch({
           type: types.LOAD_USER_NAME,
           name : ''
 })
```

**My reducer**

```
import types from './../constants/actions'

const userName = (state = {userName : "N/A"}, action) => {
console.log('inside reducer'); //<----- CONSOLE.LOG
switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_USER_NAME:
        console.log('before change state')
        return action.data;
    default:
        return '_N/A'
}
}

export {userName}
```

**./constants/actions**

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
LOAD_USER_NAME : 'LOAD_USER_NAME'

})
```

afte execution I see in the console following information:

[image]

I hoped to see in the console at least one more time `inside reducer` which mean that my reducer was call.

Comment: Try changing `let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, {` to `var store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, {`

Comment: have you tried resolving response.json() before calling on store.dispatch?

Comment: @Davidlrnt yes, I can read data from `response.json()`

Comment: @Panther I did you recommendation, the result without changes

Comment: hope this helps.

    const f = fetch("/сurrentUserName", {credentials: 'same-origin'})
    .then(response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log ('status = ' + response.status)//<----- CONSOLE.LOG
        store.dispatch({
           type: types.LOAD_USER_NAME,
           name : data.message
       })
    });

Comment: @Panther thank you but the result is the same. I deleted fetch function and tried to call dispath and the result the same, so problem not in fetch

Comment: `Javascript promises swallows errors`. My suggestion is add a `catch` and see if it executes, else start debugging by stepping into each line and you will find the swallowed error.

Comment: Can you provide the content of action object in reducer ?

Comment: @JSantosh it just a constant and it present in question. Please see `./constants/actions`

Comment: Need some correction in code. Action is dispatching payload with key as `name`, reducer is expecting `action.data`.  Secondly, how does the state modified in the reducer? returning `action.data` does not do anything in redux state store.

Comment: Provide the values of `action.type, types.LOAD_USER_NAME`

Comment: @JSantosh @anoop the problem somewhere in another place. Even if logic in reducre isn't correct I should see in console text `inside reducer` after figure `1`. I will mean that redux call reducer.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in my code is apply middleware.

I substited this code:

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(logger)(createStore);

let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, {
    userName: 'N/A'
});
```

On the following one:

```
const log = logger();

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    {
      userName : 'N/A'
    },
    applyMiddleware(log)
);
```

and all start working